# total price of products laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need the sum of prices in my order for my webshop I have this:

```
  @foreach($order->orderrow as $orderrow)
            {{  $product = $orderrow->product->latest_price->price }}
  @endforeach
```

this will show all the prices in the order,
the order is build with an orderrow here are the products for the order, the prices are in an single table.

there for in the

**Product model**

```
public function price() {
    return $this->hasMany(Price::class);
}
public function latest_price() {
    return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->orderBy('date', 'desc');
}
```

when i try to do the sum for with the latest_price it will get all the prices in my database sum upped

```
 @foreach($order->orderrow as $orderrow)
            {{  $product = $orderrow->product->latest_price->sum('price') }}
  @endforeach
```

it will sum up all the prices in the table of price.

Comment: Are you wanting to get the sum for the entire order?

Comment: yes i want to sum for the entire order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sum` the total price of the `$order` in the controller then send it with the `$order` to the view:

```
 $totalOrderPrice = 0;
 foreach($order->orderrow as $orderrow){
         $totalOrderPrice += $orderrow->product->latest_price->price;
 }
 return view('yourViewName')->with(['totalOrderPrice'=>$totalOrderPrice,'order'=>$order]);
```

Comment: Makdous is this even possible if the order is showed in the users show.blade.php

Comment: @RicardoPlompen Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the [sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sum) method on the collection:

```
$totalOrderPrice = $order->orderrow->sum(function ($orderRow) {
    return $orderRow->product->latest_price->price;
});
```

The above assumes that `$order->orderrow` is a collection. If it isn't you could simply wrap it with `collect(...)` to get the same results i.e.:

```
$totalOrderPrice = collect($order->orderrow)->sum(function ($orderRow) {
    return $orderRow->product->latest_price->price;
});
```